# Merging dataframes based on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

How can I merge 2 dataframe `df1` and `df2` in order to get `df3` that has the rows of `df1` and `df2` that have the same index (and the same values in the columns)?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A2', 'A3', 'A7'],
                        'B': ['B0', 'B2', 'B3', 'B7'],
                        'C': ['C0', 'C2', 'C3', 'C7'],
                        'D': ['D0', 'D2', 'D3', 'D7']},
                         index=[0, 2, 3,7])
```

## test 1

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A7'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B7'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C7'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D7']},
                     index=[0, 1, 2, 7])
```

## test 2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A1'],
                    'B': ['B1'],
                    'C': ['C1'],
                    'D': ['D1']},
                     index=[1])
```

## Expected output test 1

```
Out[13]: 
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
7  A7  B7  C7  D7
```

## Expected output test 2

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 2):

Just `merge`:

```
In[111]:
df1.merge(df2)

Out[111]: 
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
```

The default params for `merge` is to merge all columns, performing an `inner` merge so only where all values agree

Looking at the index matching requirement, I'd filter the df prior to the merge:

```
In[131]:
filtered = df1.loc[df2.index].dropna()
filtered

Out[131]: 
    A   B   C   D
1  A1  B1  C1  D1
```

and then merge

```
In[132]:
filtered.merge(df2)
Out[132]: 
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
```

if the indices do not match at all, say the first row of `df2` is `1` instead of `2`:

```
In[133]:
filtered = df1.loc[df2.index].dropna()
filtered
Out[133]: 
    A   B   C   D
1  A1  B1  C1  D1
```

then `merge` will return an empty df because the index row value doesn't agree:

```
In[134]:
filtered.merge(df2)

Out[132]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D]
Index: []
```

**UPDATE**

On your new dataset, `merge` will reset the index which is the default behaviour:

```
In[152]:
filtered.merge(df2)

Out[152]: 
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A2  B2  C2  D2
2  A7  B7  C7  D7
```

So to retain the indices, we can just make a boolean mask using the equality operator and call `dropna` so that any rows with any `NaN` values which will occur where the values don't agree will get dropped, this should handle all cases:

```
In[153]:
filtered[filtered== df2.loc[filtered.index]].dropna()

Out[153]: 
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
7  A7  B7  C7  D7
```

Comment: I've edited the question with a different test case... not sure the solution that you gave works for this case..

Comment: It gives the right rows but doesn't preserve the indices, it seems.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ indices are ignored when merging on columns, semantically I think `merge` is the correct approach, I'll update to show how to get this to work as posted

Comment: @EdChum the problem of this solution is that if there are not common indeces the merge will give a warining... any idea how to solve it?, I added the test case in the question

Comment: actually it gives an error KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"

Comment: If you have a new question then please post a new question, you're now proposing to change your question for the second time, each time requires fundamentally different answers, this is bad practice on SO. My answer, answers your question as posted, you asked about matching on indices and column values and position, now you're stating it won't work with common index values which is fundamentally different

Comment: it's also not a valid point because after the initial call to `filtered = df1.loc[df2.index].dropna()` you get an empty df anyway

Comment: Well I think the question is the same...just the input changes... I haven't changed the question.. just changed/updated the test cases because the answer didn't cover these cases... If you think it is relevant I can post another question, but it will be the same as this one.

Comment: My last comment is still valid, the filtered df will be empty so there isn't any need to do anything further after this

Comment: `df1.merge(df2)` returns an empty df

Comment: maybe I misunderstand, but before that filtered = df1.loc[df2.index].dropna()
 and then filtered.merge(df2) and then filtered[filtered== df2.loc[filtered.index]].dropna()

Comment: was this your suggested solution?

Comment: You have 2 things to try `merge` which won't retain the indices, and filtering which will but will raise a KeyError because there are no common indices, it's pretty simple to test if there are any common indices first prior to filtering

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the values are the same you can do:

```
df1.loc[df1.index.to_series().isin(df2.index)]
```

Theres no need to do a merge.

Comment: Semantically this is just matching on indices and not column or column values which is not what the OP's question is about

Comment: Well, thats exactly what he asked. He doesn't want to merge data from two dataframes, he just wants to filter based on the index.